# Nova (by Panic) Theme Development (new theme not selectable)

Tags: nova-editor

I would like to develop an editor theme, or two, for Panic's Nova IDE. The "create new extension command" has set up the skeleton of files for me, but I can't figure out what needs to be changed to get my new theme to display in Nova's Theme Preferences pane.

So I'm looking for clues...

Answer (score 2):

During development you can click **Extensions > Activate Project as Extension** to immediately see the theme in settings and preview changes.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've created your Theme extension, just find the local file "foo.novaextension" using Finder. Then, double-click this file and Nova will ask if you want to install it. The theme should now be selectable from the Preferences panel.